# Filter outlook emails by time and day

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

so i need to count emails which are outside of office hours timing for the past 1 year.

Is there any way that i can filter emails with this condition in outlook?

Because it is very tedious to check and count manually.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You can use the Advanced Find dialog box, adding field criteria to the Advanced tab

Comment: Cannot select time example after 6pm

Answer (score 0):

It may be tedious to start with, but the best way I can come up with is by using email categories and manually setting each relevant email to an `Out of Office` category.

1. Set up an `Out of Office` category by clicking **Categorize → All Categories... → New**.
2. Manually categorize all the relevant emails as `Out of Office`
3. When you want the total `Out of Office` emails you just sort your emails by `Category`.  The emails will be shown in groups by `Category` with the totals on top.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for this. But you can use the free [Outlook Message Statistics by Hour](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookStatisticsMessageHour) utility to easily count emails by each hour of the day. It allows you to run it in a non-domain enviroment. In domain enviroment, you'll need the advanced version of the mentioned tool developed by my company.